# QSharedMemory across two different processes

Tags: c++, qt, ipc

I want to share a variable across two different Qt applications. I am thinking of using QSharedMemory for this purpose. The problem I am facing is to identify the shared memory regions in the Qt applications. How do I ensure that both applications use the same Shared Memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shared memory area is identified by a key - a string argument passed to the [constructor](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsharedmemory.html#QSharedMemory), or set later using [`setKey`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsharedmemory.html#setKey).

You need to generate a key and pass its value to both applications; using that, they will both access the same shared memory.

Comment: Does using a plain QString serve the purpose?

Comment: @saurabhsood91: The string can be anything you like, as long as (a) both applications are given the same key, and (b) it doesn't clash with a key used by any other application.

Answer (score 2):

On top of what Mike Seymour already said Qt has a lot of example code (that most likely is also on your system), so you can check this [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-ipc-sharedmemory-example.html) and also [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedmemory.html)